# Display border on button not working (CSS)

Tags: css

I have a page where I try to add a border with a width of 3px to a button, but it just doesn't show. I've tried everything I know but can't get it to work.

The page where I can't get it to work is this one: https://capsulehotel.ch/produkte/
(It's the buttons with the text "WERDE HOTELBESITZER", "LIEGENSCHAFT ANBIETEN",...)

This is the CSS code I've tried:

```
.popupbutton2 {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    border-width: 3px !important;
    border-color: #000000 !important;
    border-radius: 8px !important;
}
```

An here is a page where the buttons look how I want them to look: https://capsulehotel.ch/

Comment: add `border-style: solid;`

Comment: And don't use `!important` to avoid other problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed `border style` i.e `border-style: solid;`

Instead of doing:

```
border-width: 3px !important; 
border-color: #000000 !important;
```

Make it in single line:

```
border: 3px solid #000000;
```

It is working on your site:

[image: Border fix]

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `border-style` with it.

```css
.popupbutton2 {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: #000000;
    border-radius: 8px;
    border-style: solid; /* you can try other values also */
}
```

**Note:** I've removed all `!important` from your styles.

Comment: Thank you for your help. The style was missing.